# Why Does Assigning console.log to a variable cause an illegal invocation?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following block of code, inserted into a document.

```
<script>
    var l = console.log;
    l('Hello world');
</script>
// TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Why does this script cause in illegal invocation? I can't see anything that is unusual here. Also, how would you get this to work?

Comment: `var l = console.log.bind(console);`

Comment: In Opera, this does work without problems :-)

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Thanks that about explains it LOL